# My Update button changes all elements in database when clicked on Button

Tags: c#

I am have a form with three buttons (save , update and delete button). Each time i click on a button it executes a defined command. The difficulties i have is that the update button does not work correctly. When i click on it, it updates all elements in the database into a single word. Please i need assistance.
Thanks.

```
        string nom = NomTxt.Text;
        string prenom = preTxt.Text;

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Rahimpamelo\Desktop\updatebd.accdb";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UpdateTB SET Nom='"+nom+"',Prenom='"+prenom+"'");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Update successfull");
```

[image]

Comment: You're looking for the `WHERE` keyword in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your sql statement `Where` clause.

Comment: Thank . i did not realized it

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing the `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE UpdateTB
SET Nom='nom', Prenom='prenom'
```

will update **every row**

What you want to do is

```
UPDATE UpdateTB
SET Nom='nom', Prenom='prenom'
WHERE $column = 'keyword'
```

Also, your query is vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> **You should Where condition on your query**

**Syntax**

> UPDATE table_name
>   SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
>   WHERE condition;

**Sample Code:**

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UpdateTB SET Nom='"+nom+"',Prenom='"+prenom+"' WHERE id='@User_ID'");
```